# Money transfer from Paypal to my blocked VISA card? Will I get the money?

Tags: paypal, withdrawal, visa

I made a withdrawal from my Paypal account to my VISA card. This VISA card is linked to my bank account and it usually takes about 7 days for money to arrive. This time my bank blocked my VISA next day after I made this withdrawal - someone tried to use it overseas. Will I receive my money on blocked VISA card?

Comment: I'd recommend asking the bank.

Comment: I saw this and was curious if you ever got this resolved?

Comment: I didn't know you could make a withdraw from PayPal to a VISA card. I thought you could only withdraw to a bank account. On PayPal, If I go to "Withdraw", I think it only offers bank accounts for the destinations. Right now my PayPal balance is $0 so I can't even get to the withdraw page, I'll have to check this next time I have a PayPal balance. Perhaps if I only had CC account (not bank/checking) linked to PayPal?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I would expect so--the block from spending funds probably does not put a block in place for receiving funds.  But ask your bank.

Expect a 50% chance that they give you the wrong answer.  (Some banks are better than others, but on average this is how often I have found bank employees to be incorrect about anything nonstandard).

It may help to ask the bank how often it happens and who actually sorts out problems with blocked cards--and then talk to that person.  Then you should only expect a 25% chance that they are wrong.

Comment: I totally agree with you about the probability of right answer from any bank. I asked them and they can not give me confident answer. They just mumbling something that sounds more like "no".

Comment: Yes, I always phone the bank three times with the same question when it's non-standard. And make sure I speak to a different person each time.I hope it's not 50%, but the wrong answer probability is very high.